# How to CURL a URL and POST the content in a file as a param

Tags: curl

I want to post the content of a file as a param to a URL with CURL.
Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Use `-d '@/path/to/file/url_encoded_file.ext'`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way to to post the content of a file to an url. curl's man page has examples for exactly this case.